# What is Time and space complexity to find The Maximum Sum in Triangle From Top to Bottom

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, dynamic-programming, space-complexity

The algorithm is as follows: What is the best and worst time and space complexity to find the Maximum Sum in Triangle From Top to Bottom

```
For each ELEMENT in particular ROW and COLUMN

{

If ( ELEMENT is FIRST ELEMENT  of ROW)

{

MAX_SUM[ROW][COLUMN] = ELEMENT + FIRST element of (ROW-1)

}

Else If (ELEMENT is LAST ELEMENT of ROW)

{

MAX_SUM[ROW][COLUMN] = ELEMENT + LAST element of (ROW-1)

}

Else

{

MAX_SUM[ROW][COLUMN] = ELEMENT + maximum( element at [ROW-1][COLUMN-1], element at [ROW-1][COLUMN])

//recursive formula calculating max_sum at each point from all possible paths till that point

}

}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint: the best time and space complexity is achieved by finding it from bottom to top :)

Comment: Your wording is unclear: how is the "sum" in a "triangle" defined? Do you mean a triangular area of cells in a table?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-path-sum-triangle/ refer this link for clarification.

Comment: You should never refer to a link for the problem description because it is a waste of time for readers. You should include the minimum sufficient description - an "MVCE" (Minimum Verifiable Concrete Example)

Answer (score 1):

The clue is in the first line of the code:

> `For each ELEMENT in particular ROW and COLUMN`

There are no nested loops. Therefore the time complexity is directly proportional to the *total number of elements*, i.e. `O(N^2)` where `N` is the number of rows.